# Using pqxx cursors

Tags: postgresql, libpqxx

I am trying to learn how to use cursors in pqxx.

I found `pqxx::cursor_base` in the reference and there are several subclasses that derive from `pqxx::cursor_base`.

After Googling the topic for hours, I can't find any sample code or anything explaining how to use `pqxx` cursors.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

There are surprisingly few cursor examples to be found.  Here's what I use:

```
      const std::conStr("user=" + opt::dbUser + " password=" + opt::dbPasswd + " host=" + opt::dbHost + " dbname=" + opt::dbName);                                            

      pqxx::connection conn(connStr);
      pqxx::work txn(conn);
      std::string selectString = "SELECT id, name FROM table_name WHERE condition";

      pqxx::stateless_cursor<pqxx::cursor_base::read_only, pqxx::cursor_base::owned> 
      cursor(txn, selectString, "myCursor", false);

      //cursor variables
      size_t idx = 0;       //starting location
      size_t step = 10000;  //number of rows for each chunk
      pqxx::result result;
      do{
        //get next cursor chunk and update the index
        result = cursor.retrieve( idx, idx + step );
        idx += step;

        size_t records = result.size();
        cout << idx << ": records pulled = " << records << endl;

        for( pqxx::result::const_iterator row : result ){
          //iterate over cursor rows
        }
      }
      while( result.size() == step ); //if the result.size() != step, we're on our last loop
      cout << "Done!" << endl;
```